# .*? does not match character before word boundary

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I have a hard time understanding why `((?i)\bb.*?\b)` returns `b` and not `b-` for the string `a b- c`. I also tried `((?i)\bb\w*\b)`, but that does not work any better.

**Some more info:**

I need to match words in a text. I need to retrieve all words that start with the letter `b`. And 'words' means pretty much any character string that starts with a `b`, such as `b`, `b-`, `b'`, `b"` etc. The 'words' I need to match are not of course limited with a space such as in the example.

Comment: It's not including it because you have a lazy regex `.*?`. But, what are you trying to accomplish anyway?

Comment: The `.` "Matches any single character except \n".  `-` is not a character.  `\w` is equivalent to [a-zA-Z_0-9], which does not include `-`

Comment: @bokibeg Added some more info...

Comment: @SwDevMan81: `-` **is** a character.  You seem to be using "character" to mean "letter", which is pretty common, but in this case it means *anything* (letter, digit, punctuation, whitespace...).  The only character that `.` does not match (in the .NET flavor) is a linefeed (`\n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

`(b.*?)(?:\s|$)`

I've tested it on `a b- c bfdf b32=" dfa b. b---s asd b`.

It seems like you're not looking for *words* but any string starting with a letter "b" delimited by a space (or other?) character(s). Your original pattern can't work because "-" doesn't qualify as part of a word. Good luck.

Note: Above pattern is very simple, the last part with $ is there so that the last "b" is captured which is on the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is called a "greedy" [quantifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx). It'll match as many iterations of the preceding pattern as possible. Most of the time, this is exactly what you want, but sometimes you want to use a "lazy" quantifier, meaning it'll match as *few* as possible, including 0.

To make a quantifier "lazy", you add a question mark: `*?`, `+?`, `??`, etc.

Now, the next part of the answer is how [word boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordBoundary) work. Word boundaries will match a *position* where there's a "break" between "word characters" (0-9, a-z and _) and "non-word characters". `-` is a non-word character, so the positions between `b-`, `-c` and `c` would all work.

Because you've got a lazy quantifier and there's a word boundary immediately after the `b`, that's all that your regex will match.

Rather than trying to use a word boundary to find the end of your word, just match word characters and dashes, like so, which will naturally match everything to the "end" of the word:

```
\bb[-\w]*
```

See a [working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbb%5b-%5cw%5d*&i=a+bb-c+d)

Answer (score 0):

`.*?` is minimal, so `b.*?\b` finds the first word boundary after the `b`.  Since `b` is a word character, and `-` is not, that first word boundary is between those characters.

ETA: Thing is, regexen don't consider your 'words' to be words, so `\b` won't work for them.  You say your 'words' don't always end with a space.  And, obviously, they won't end with a hyphen.  How, more precisely do they end?